# Firebase functions after change in storage. Detect the what change was made

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to detect which change was made after `exports.fileUploaded = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {})` is called. Because this is called when file is **uploaded** to storage and even when file was removed **from** sotrage

I can get file exists from `object.resourceState==="not_exists"`,  what about others **update**, **create**,

Comment: I think due to documentation, I understood you may use `.onCreated, .onModified, or .onDeleted`  events too. You can check `event.data`  object for the modification results. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look more closely at the [ObjectMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata) event properties.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#detect_resourcestate_and_other_event_attributes):

> Cloud Functions exposes a number of event attributes such as a
>   timestamp and resource for the change, and size and contentType for
>   the file updated. The resourceState attribute for an event has the
>   value "exists" (for object creation and updates) or "not_exists" (for
>   object deletion and moves). The resourceState attribute should be
>   paired with the 'metageneration' attribute if you want to know if an
>   object was just created. The metageneration attributed is incremented
>   whenever there's a change to the object's metadata. For new objects,
>   the metageneration value is 1.

Between `resourceState` and `metageneration` you should be able to figure out what happened.